# How to remove accents/diacritics in a string with pentaho?

Tags: pentaho

I'm trying to remove accents with Pentaho. It's possible use regular expression, but is there another simpler way?

I'm using Pentaho 6.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is use a `Modified Java Script` step using apache commons. This lib is already packaged inside the tool. With the following code you are ready to go:

```
COLUMN_SANITIZED = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.stripAccents(COLUMN_SANITIZED);
```

Don't forget do add this column in the fields section in `Modified Java Script` with option  `Replace value 'Fieldname' or 'Rename To'` to Yes.